# How to modify the way an object is casted into an array?

Tags: php, php-5.6

I have to convert an object into an array, but I want to omit some of the objects' properties.

```php
class X {
   protected $a = 1;
   protected $b = 5;

   /**
    * Property 'a' should not exist in the resulting array
    */
   public function __toArrayOrSomething()
   {
       return [
           'b' => $this->b
       ];
   }
}
```

When I cast an object of this class into an array, the resulting array should e. g. look like this:

```php
$x = new X();
$result = (array) $x;
```

`$result` should look like this:

```
[
    'b' => 5
]
```

I know there are dozens of ways to do a manual array conversion, but I need a solution for use with type-casting (`$y = (array) $x;`).

So the question is:
Is there something like JsonSerializable::jsonSerialize for array-casting?

Or in other words: Is there a method that is called, when an object is casted into an array?

Comment: Maybe it's better to implement `ArrayAccess`?

Comment: PHP has that kind of logic for string conversion, you can implement the magic method `__toString` for that, but there is no direct equivalent __toArray.